# Is there any way to call exception handler method without @enableWebMvc in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, filter, exceptionhandler

Using Exception handler i want to return new response and break the original handler response.if CustomException is thrown from filter.

i have tried below code but handler method is not called.

```
private boolean istest = true;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    KPICounterHelper.incrementRequestCounter(request);
    if(istest) {
        throw new CustomException("kd ex",55);
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    KPICounterHelper.incrementResponseCounter(request);


}

   //this is handler code
   @RestControllerAdvice
     public class ExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler(value= 
   {CustomException.class})
public CustomException handleCustom() {
    System.out.println("in handler");
    return new CustomException("kd excccc", 565);
}

      }

    //application.properties

     spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
     spring.resources.add-mappings=fals
```

i want to execute handler code and return response from there.
and want to execute method code after chain.doFilter()

Comment: did you debug when you throw the exception on line return new CustomException("kd excccc", 565);?  is it entering?

Comment: yes i did but it is not entering in handler.

Comment: Okay so could you change your code for this:
 @ExceptionHandler(value 
      = { CustomException.class })
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(
      CustomException ex, WebRequest request) {
        String bodyOfResponse = "This should be application specific";
          new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
    }

Comment: And debug it again please... let me know what happens...